# Unhandle flutter Exception

Tags: flutter

[I tried to solve this problem but it gave same problem again and again if any have faced the same problem and they solve the problem will you give me the solution on the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjOAb.jpg)

I have tried to set environment variables according to video but it doesn't work. I also see the website but they show me different problems